# Delete all the cells of the Databricks Notebook

Tags: databricks, spark-notebook

I am working on Databricks notebook for some of the spark work that I am doing. I am using notebook just as a proof of concept work initially and then organized that so that I can create jar out of it. As I am doing POC I try adding lot of cells to experiment different ways. Over a period of time the notebook has large number of cells and most of the stuffs is not required as I have organized that and move to a finalized notebook/Jar code. I am deleting the cells one by one but that can be time consuming. So I just wanted to know if there is a way to delete all the cells from the notebook at one.

There is one option at the top of the notebook that says delete cells but when I click on that it just deletes the single cell and not all the cells from the notebook.

Snapshot of the top UI where I see option of delete cells is as below :

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you work with Databricks notebooks, you can work in the two modes, similar to the VI editor:

1. **Edit mode**, when you edit the code of the individual cells
2. **Command mode** - in this case, you're working not with the code, but with the cells, so you can select several cells at once, cut/copy/paste/delete them, etc. (see [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/notebooks-use.html) or click on the `Shortcuts` in the `?` item of UI).

From the documentation you will see that in the command mode (press ESC to enter into it) you can select all cells, or you can use Shift + cursor to select several cells, and then you can press `d` two times, and this will trigger deletion of the selected cells.

Comment: Thanks @Alex_Ott for the link to the documentation. I did not knew there were two modes that we can use when working with databricks notebook.

Comment: for some reason, pressing D twice didn't work for me. after selecting the cells to be deleted, i clicked on 'Edit' -> 'Delete cell' is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

After I went through @AlexOtt answer I tried that using the UI and it worked.

If you want to delete all the cells in a notebook then first you need to click on the `select all cells` option in the context menu. this would select all the cells that are present in the notebook and now if you select the option of `delete cells` then it would delete all the cells.

This was confusing as the option was showing text as delete cells and deleting only the cell that had the cursor but now I know how I can do it, UI options makes sense but could have been more user friendly.